# Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker datetime picker reset through external javascript call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have use **Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker version : 4.17.47**, now explain scenario when I open bootstrap-datetimepicker from text box & selected date after that I have one clear button onclick I have clear that value, but when I am going back to open datetimepicker its shows previously selected date as **highlighted**. So issue is datetimepicker is not reset, I want to reset that datetime picker on cancel click external JavaScript call.

I have use below but non of them is working

```
$('#myDatepicker').data('datepicker').setDate(null);

$('#myDatepicker').data().DateTimePicker.date(null);
```

And also if I have two datetimepicker like fromdate to todate it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

> [clear()](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#clear): Clears the datepicker by setting the value to null

Instead, if you need only to reset the selected day you can:

- save a property: if true the reset button has been clicked, if not no reset
- on show and update events of datepicker you can test if the reset button has been clicked.. If yes, remove the active class for selected day
- on change event of datepicker the previous property set can be reset.

```js
$('#myDatepicker').datetimepicker().prop("resetDatePicker", false).on('dp.update dp.show', function(e) {
    if ($('#myDatepicker').prop("resetDatePicker")) {
        $(this).find('td.day.active').removeClass('active today');
    }
}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
    $('#myDatepicker').prop("resetDatePicker", false);
});


$('#resetDatePicker').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#myDatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date(moment());
    $('#myDatepicker').prop("resetDatePicker", true).find(':input').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"/>




<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <button id="resetDatePicker" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have just tested this scenario & found that if i select date like 02/02/2013 & write cancel button click code same like you provide in demo. it removes selection of previously selected date but its not reset whole calander control & provide today's date as selected date.

Comment: You still understand wrong i select date like 02 Feb 2013 from dattimepicker & press clear button & now again open datetimepicker its shows previously selected year & month. its not reset & display like whenever we render it for first time.

Comment: Steps written to produce issue: 1) select Date from demo snippet (you make for give me as answer) like i am selecting date 02-Feb-2013. 2) press Clear button 3) again open calendar 4) As you show it shows Feb month and year as 2013. this is what i am explaining to you in previous comments.

Comment: So its need to be reset